# Confused about how Controllers actually map to views in this case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, actionmethod

I have these two URL's I want to make available to my users:

```
/Account/Orders   <- This would should be a grid of all orders.
/Account/Orders/132   <- This would show this particular order information.
```

Here are my two ActionMethods:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Orders(int id)
{
    using (var orderRepository = new EfOrderRepository())
    using (var accountRepository = new EfAccountRepository())
    {
        OrderModel model = new OrderModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Orders()
{
    using (var orderRepository = new EfOrderRepository())
    using (var accountRepository = new EfAccountRepository())
    {            
        List<OrderModel> model = new List<OrderModel>();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If my Orders view is strongly typed with an `OrderModel` as the model, the `Orders()` action method won't work as I need to pass it an IEnumerable instead of a single object.

What do you suggest in this case? This seems like something that's easy to do, but I've had a very long (productive!) day, but I can only go so far.

Comment: Use an Edit (or list)  method and Index method to be a bit more in the 'standard' MVC realm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

1) Setup your routes with the most specific one first

```
MapRoute("first", "/Accounts/Orders/{id}" ....
           controller="mycontroller" action="details"
MapRoute("second", "/Accounts/Orders .....
           controller="mycontroller" action="summary"
```

2) Instead of routes have two get methods with different signatures:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexDetails(int id)
{
}

Routing should match the

Comment: Man was I tired last night... the routes setting is the obvious solution to this one. Thanks for starting my brain up again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the default routes, your second `Order` method will never be called. The route is going to fill in the missing `id` parameter with a null value if one is not supplied, and try to call the overload with the `id` parameter.

You could change up your routes or do other things to try and get around this, but the faster option is to just work within the routing system:

```
public ActionResult Orders(int id = -1)
{
  return id == -1 ? this.OrdersSummary() : this.OrdersDetail(id);
}

private ActionResult OrdersSummary()
{
  var model = new SummaryModel();
  // fill in model;
  return this.View("OrdersSummary", model);
}

private ActionResult OrdersDetail(int id) 
{
  var model = new DetailModel();
  // fill in model;
  return this.View("OrderDetail", model);
}
```

Comment: You can also use a nullable int (int? id) and check id.HasValue instead of forcing a -1.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different views. One for the grid and one for the order detail.

Then you can call them like this:

```
return View("OrderGrid", Orders); // for grid

return View("OrderDetail", Order); // for detail
```

Comment: I get an error before that area of code is even reached, it says that only an optional parameter must be null. Meaning that when visiting `Accounts/Orders` I'm reaching the wrong ActionMethod.